# Annotation label clipped in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, annotate

I'm trying to avoid the bottom annotation being clipped. It's the descender on the "p" that gets chopped off. I've used the "inward" option on vjust.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(as.Date("2020-01-01"),as.Date("2022-01-01"))
                     ,y=c(0,1))
df
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  annotate("text",x=mean(df$x),y=-Inf,label="Clipped",hjust=0.5,vjust="inward",size=12,colour="red") +
  annotate("text",x=mean(df$x),y=Inf,label="Not Clipped",hjust=0.5,vjust="inward",size=12,colour="blue")
```

[image: clipped text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach would be to use the `min` and `max` y values:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-01")),
  y = c(0, 1)
)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  annotate("text", x = mean(df$x), y = min(df$y), label = "Clipped", hjust = 0.5, vjust = "inward", size = 12, colour = "red") +
  annotate("text", x = mean(df$x), y = max(df$y), label = "Not Clipped", hjust = 0.5, vjust = "inward", size = 12, colour = "blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Carl, that's probably what I'll go for. I'm surprised that ggplot2 doesn't handle this well by default but I guess there's a logic to it given the elegance of the package as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Looks like this issue is related to what is chosen as the base line to align the text labels. This could be seen clearly when switching to `geom_label` where we see that for the clipped label the base line chosen for the alignment is not the end of the "p". Hence the "p"s get clipped off:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  annotate("label", x = mean(df$x), y = -Inf, label = "Clipped", 
           hjust = 0.5, vjust = "inward", size = 12, colour = "red", label.padding = unit(0, "lines")) +
  annotate("label", x = mean(df$x), y = Inf, label = "Not Clipped", 
           hjust = 0.5, vjust = "inward", size = 12, colour = "blue", label.padding = unit(0, "lines"))
```

[image]

One possible fix would be to switch to `ggtext::GeomRichtext`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  annotate(ggtext::GeomRichtext, x = mean(df$x), y = -Inf, label = "Clipped", 
           hjust = 0.5, vjust = "inward", size = 12, colour = "red", 
           label.size = 0, fill = NA, label.padding = unit(0, "lines")) +
  annotate(ggtext::GeomRichtext, x = mean(df$x), y = Inf, label = "Not Clipped", 
           hjust = 0.5, vjust = "inward", size = 12, colour = "blue", 
           label.size = 0, fill = NA, label.padding = unit(0, "lines"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @stefan I hadn't come across that package

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to be clipped on the same position, you can use `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")`:

```r
df <- data.frame(x=c(as.Date("2020-01-01"),as.Date("2022-01-01"))
                 ,y=c(0,1))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  annotate("text",x=mean(df$x),y=-Inf,label="Clipped",hjust=0.5,vjust="inward",size=12,colour="red") +
  annotate("text",x=mean(df$x),y=Inf,label="Not Clipped",hjust=0.5,vjust="inward",size=12,colour="blue") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>